# SQL SUBSTR no effect when put -4

Tags: sql, proc

I am doing Proc SQL in SAS EG.

Below is the code. I have tried STRIP and CAT. The beginning is the first letter while remove the last 4 words from VALUENAME. However, it will not remove the last 4 words from VALUENAME. If i change the substr to 1,4 then it will display the result with 4 characters. Need your help to remove the last 4 words from VALUENAME.

```
PROC SQL;
SELECT 
 SUBSTR(STRIP(VALUENAME),1,-4) as valuename,
 columnname
FROM GETUOM
WHERE VALUENAME IS NOT NULL;
QUIT;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
PROC SQL;
SELECT 
 SUBSTR(STRIP(VALUENAME),1,LENGTH(VALUENAME)-4) as valuename,
 columnname
FROM GETUOM
WHERE VALUENAME IS NOT NULL;
QUIT;
```